# accessing civicrm in lan

Tags: permissions, civicrm-home, settings, civicrm.settings.php

I am running Civicrm wordpress in my PC and I want to access it through LAN. When I am trying to run the site from other machines using http://myipaddress/site, the login page opens fine. but in the next links the URL redirects to http://localhost/

Should I have to change in code in all places from localhost to my ip address? any easy way to do it without missing any files?

Using WAMP 3.0.6

Comment: This question seems identical to the one you asked 6 hours ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to update your Base URL with your IP address - because your base URL is pointing to localhost that is why your remote PC is redirecting to localhost

change the BaseURL to your IP address and that should fix the issue

I guess this helps!!!